# ImageView crashing custom adapter at getView()

Tags: android, android-listview, imageview

My list view is crashing at getView. When the application first loads it works well but as soon as I as navigate away from it or I take a screenshot and try to share the app crashes. This is the custom adapter.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private List<AlarmItem> alarms;
private Context context;

public CustomAdapter(List<AlarmItem> alarms,Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.alarms = alarms;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return alarms.size();
}

@Override
public AlarmItem getItem(int position) {
    return alarms.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    final AlarmItem item = getItem(position);
    Holder holder;

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_alarm_row,parent,false);
        holder = new Holder();
        holder.image= (RoundedImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
        holder.wakeText =(RobotoLight)convertView.findViewById(R.id.waketext);
        holder.name =(RobotoRegular)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.period = (RobotoLight)convertView.findViewById(R.id.period);
        holder.time = (RobotoRegular)convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        holder.day1 =(RobotoLight)convertView.findViewById(R.id.day1);
        holder.day2 =(RobotoLight)convertView.findViewById(R.id.day2);
        holder.day3 =(RobotoLight)convertView.findViewById(R.id.day3);
        holder.day4 =(RobotoLight)convertView.findViewById(R.id.day4);
        holder.day5 =(RobotoLight)convertView.findViewById(R.id.day5);
        holder.day6 =(RobotoLight)convertView.findViewById(R.id.day6);
        holder.day7 =(RobotoLight)convertView.findViewById(R.id.day7);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (Holder)convertView.getTag();
    }


    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(holder.image, "http://graph.facebook.com/" + item.getProfileId().trim() + "/picture?style=large");


    holder.wakeText.setText(context.getString(R.string.wake_message));
    holder.name.setText(item.getName()+" ");
    holder.period.setText(item.getPeriod());
    holder.time.setText(item.getTime());

    /**
     * This block code places sets the color of the particular day. If its active
     * It sets it to a particular colour if not then the inactive colour remains.
     */
    List<RobotoLight> dayList = new ArrayList<RobotoLight>();
    dayList.add(holder.day1);
    dayList.add(holder.day2);
    dayList.add(holder.day3);
    dayList.add(holder.day4);
    dayList.add(holder.day5);
    dayList.add(holder.day6);
    dayList.add(holder.day7);


    for(int x=0;x<7;x++)
    {
        /**
         * if the day at a particular point in the string is equal to one that means its active
         * therefore set active color.
         */
        if(item.getDays().charAt(x) == '1')
        {
             dayList.get(x).setTextColor(R.color.alarm_day_active);
        }
        else
        {
            dayList.get(x).setTextColor(R.color.alarm_day_inactive);
        }
    }


    return convertView;
}

public static class Holder
{

    RoundedImageView image;
    RobotoLight wakeText;
    RobotoRegular name;
    RobotoLight period;
    RobotoRegular time;
    RobotoLight day1;
    RobotoLight day2;
    RobotoLight day3;
    RobotoLight day4;
    RobotoLight day5;
    RobotoLight day6;
    RobotoLight day7;
}



}
```

This my log cat

```
    09-04 08:02:45.948: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9402): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.wake.friend.adapter.AlarmAdapter.getView(AlarmAdapter.java:82)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2334)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1937)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1483)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1765)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2178)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4380)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4380)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4380)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1141)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
```

And line 82 that they are saying the null pointer exception is being thrown at is this.

```
UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(holder.image, "http://graph.facebook.com/" + item.getProfileId().trim() + "/picture?style=large");
```

I am using an image downloading helper to retrieve images from the web.

Comment: The error must be in this snippet item.getProfileId().trim()

Comment: thats not causing the error.

Comment: Have you used Log.d(String, String) to check its not null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this error is occurring is because you are accessing elements of your holder class outside the  if statement that checked if convertView was null. Therefore it works the first time but when the list view is called again and the convertView isn't null then the holder can't be accessed in the same way.Therefore its best if you put all assignment inside that if function like so.

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private List<AlarmItem> alarms;
private Context context;

public CustomAdapter(List<AlarmItem> alarms,Context context)
{
this.context = context;
this.alarms = alarms;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
return alarms.size();
}

@Override
public AlarmItem getItem(int position) {
return alarms.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
return position;
}

@Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
 {

final AlarmItem item = getItem(position);
Holder holder;

if(convertView==null)
{
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_alarm_row,parent,false);
    holder = new Holder();
    holder.image= (RoundedImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
    holder.wakeText =(RobotoLight)convertView.findViewById(R.id.waketext);
    holder.name =(RobotoRegular)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    holder.period = (RobotoLight)convertView.findViewById(R.id.period);
    holder.time = (RobotoRegular)convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
    holder.day1 =(RobotoLight)convertView.findViewById(R.id.day1);
    holder.day2 =(RobotoLight)convertView.findViewById(R.id.day2);
    holder.day3 =(RobotoLight)convertView.findViewById(R.id.day3);
    holder.day4 =(RobotoLight)convertView.findViewById(R.id.day4);
    holder.day5 =(RobotoLight)convertView.findViewById(R.id.day5);
    holder.day6 =(RobotoLight)convertView.findViewById(R.id.day6);
    holder.day7 =(RobotoLight)convertView.findViewById(R.id.day7);

    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(holder.image, "http://graph.facebook.com/" + item.getProfileId().trim() + "/picture?style=large");


    holder.wakeText.setText(context.getString(R.string.wake_message));
    holder.name.setText(item.getName()+" ");
    holder.period.setText(item.getPeriod());
    holder.time.setText(item.getTime());

    /**
     * This block code places sets the color of the particular day. If its active
     * It sets it to a particular colour if not then the inactive colour remains.
     */
    List<RobotoLight> dayList = new ArrayList<RobotoLight>();
    dayList.add(holder.day1);
    dayList.add(holder.day2);
    dayList.add(holder.day3);
    dayList.add(holder.day4);
    dayList.add(holder.day5);
    dayList.add(holder.day6);
    dayList.add(holder.day7);


    for(int x=0;x<7;x++)
    {
        /**
         * if the day at a particular point in the string is equal to one that means its active
         * therefore set active color.
         */
        if(item.getDays().charAt(x) == '1')
        {
             dayList.get(x).setTextColor(R.color.alarm_day_active);
        }
        else
        {
            dayList.get(x).setTextColor(R.color.alarm_day_inactive);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    holder = (Holder)convertView.getTag();
}





return convertView;
}

public static class Holder
{

RoundedImageView image;
RobotoLight wakeText;
RobotoRegular name;
RobotoLight period;
RobotoRegular time;
RobotoLight day1;
RobotoLight day2;
RobotoLight day3;
RobotoLight day4;
RobotoLight day5;
RobotoLight day6;
RobotoLight day7;
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe `item.getProfileId()` return null.